# Merging lists in recursive procedure in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to perform the following action -
i have a function that recieves a list and a number,
for each occurrance of this number it should duplicate it in the output list,
here is what i have so far:

```
(define (extendList lst num)
  (define data (car lst))
  (define nextData (cdr lst))
  (cond ((and (number? data)(= data num)) ( list num num (extendList nextData num)))
      (list? data) (list (extendList data num) (extendList nextData num))
      (else ( list data (extendList (cdr lst) num) ))))
```

The thing is that it just doesnt call to this function again in recursion - all it does is adding the next element to the output,
for example here is my input and my expected output:

```
(extendList '(6 x y 6) 6) ; output should be: (6 6 x y 6 6)
(extendList '(6 x (y 6) 6) 6) ;output should be: (6 6 x (y 6 6) 6 6)
```

but for both of the inputs it just returns the following:

```
'(6 6 x)
```

What am i doing wrong here?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. You use `cond` incorrectly. There's supposed to be a parenthesis around `(list? data) (list (extendList data num) (extendList nextData num))`

   I suggest to use bracket around each branch (bracket and parenthesis are interchangeable), so that it's easier to read:

   ```
   (define (extendList lst num)
     (define data (car lst))
     (define nextData (cdr lst))
     (cond
       [(and (number? data)(= data num)) (list num num (extendList nextData num))]
       [(list? data) (list (extendList data num) (extendList nextData num))]
       [else (list data (extendList (cdr lst) num))]))
   ```
2. You write a recursive function without a base case! What will happen if I call `(extendList '() 6)`?
3. `(list num num (extendList nextData num))` will create a list with three elements. I don't think this is what you actually want. You might want to use `list*` or `cons` instead. The same problem happens with other branches as well.

Comment: Why is the `(define data (car lst))` bad as an internal definition? The racket [style guide says](http://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Definitions%29) that `(define data (car lst))` is better because it doesn't force the indentation level to increase.

Comment: Never knew this before. I will change my answer then. Thx for telling me this!